# Cannot find module 'mongoose' with typeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I want to use await in a top-level function, and to do that typeScript requests me to put my target language in the tsconfig.json to 2017 or higher and the module to es2022. But when I do that, there is this error: "Cannot find module 'mongoose'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?"

I have already searched in a lot of places but I did not find a solution for that.

Here is some of my code:

The tsconfig.json

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
 "target": "es2022",   
"module": "es2022",
"outDir": "./build",     
"esModuleInterop": true,   
 "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
 "strict": true,  
"skipLibCheck": true 
}
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "finanzas",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "API que permite gestionar las finanzas de un nucleo familiar o individuo",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev src/index.ts",
    "start": "node build/index.js",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Andres Felipe Cuervo",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.11.97",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.44",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.3.8"
  }
}
```

And the error occurs when I import mongoose like this:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
```

if I imported it with require there is no error

Answer (score 6):

Vitals's answer didn't work for me either.

What did work was uncommenting the following in my tsconfig:

```
"moduleResolution": "node"
```

Hope that helps anyone else running into this.

Comment: This helped me with `import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'` and the vscode error went away: `Cannot find module 'mongodb'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'nodenext', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?ts(2792)`

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to comment the below line in your tsconfig.json file found in your project's base directory, just comment this line.

```
"esModuleInterop":true
```

also `deprecated @types/mongoose@5.11.97: Mongoose publishes its own types, so you do not need to install this package.`

Comment: Thanks for your response, but no, it does not work, the same error is still there. Have another idea?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue, you can include or uncomment either of these lines in the `tsconfig.json` file.

```
"moduleResolution": "node"
```

```
"module": "CommonJS"
```

Comment: The question is about how to use ES Modules, not switching to the legacy commonjs.